# Database is not connected to odoo server

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Odoo is acting strange, we are unable to fill any form or modify anything.

Seems odoo is not connected to the database and keep lagging

I have restarted the server and postgresql DB but still no progress.

if you can check the logs:

````
2019-10-05 15:10:46,952 10100 INFO ibda3vision werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Oct/2019 15:10:46] "GET /web/content/11762-a6b583b/web.report_assets_common.0.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -
2019-10-05 15:10:46,966 10100 INFO ibda3vision werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Oct/2019 15:10:46] "GET /web/content/11763-a6b583b/web.report_assets_common.1.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -
2019-10-05 15:10:47,461 10101 INFO ibda3vision odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_actions_report: The PDF report has been generated for records [840].
2019-10-05 15:10:47,520 10101 INFO ibda3vision odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_actions_report: The PDF document INVINV20190477.pdf is now saved in the database
2019-10-05 15:10:47,528 10101 INFO ibda3vision werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Oct/2019 15:10:47] "POST /report/download HTTP/1.0" 200 -
2019-10-05 15:10:48,310 10100 INFO ibda3vision werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Oct/2019 15:10:48] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/account.invoice/read HTTP/1.0" 200 -
2019-10-05 15:10:48,596 10101 INFO ibda3vision werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Oct/2019 15:10:48] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/account.invoice.line/read HTTP/1.0" 200 -
2019-10-05 15:10:48,825 10100 INFO ibda3vision werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Oct/2019 15:10:48] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/res.partner/name_get HTTP/1.0" 200 -
2019-10-05 15:10:49,237 10101 INFO ibda3vision werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Oct/2019 15:10:49] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/ir.attachment/search_read HTTP/1.0" 200 -
2019-10-05 15:11:14,678 10104 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'user=odoo sslmode=prefer dbname=ibda3vision'
2019-10-05 15:11:28,660 10106 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'user=odoo sslmode=prefer dbname=ibda3vision'
2019-10-05 15:12:22,335 10104 INFO ibda3vision odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_cron: Starting job `Mail: Fetchmail Service`.
2019-10-05 15:12:22,351 10104 INFO ibda3vision odoo.addons.fetchmail.models.fetchmail: start checking for new emails on pop server PROJECTS APPLICATIONS
2019-10-05 15:12:23,464 10104 INFO ibda3vision odoo.addons.fetchmail.models.fetchmail: start checking for new emails on pop server Recruitment
2019-10-05 15:12:26,354 10104 INFO ibda3vision odoo.addons.fetchmail.models.fetchmail: General failure when trying to fetch mail from pop server Recruitment .
2019-10-05 15:12:26,359 10104 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 3 connections to 'user=odoo sslmode=prefer dbname=ibda3vision'
2019-10-05 15:12:34,745 10106 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'user=odoo sslmode=prefer dbname=ibda3vision'
2019-10-05 15:13:30,435 10104 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'user=odoo sslmode=prefer dbname=ibda3vision'
2019-10-05 15:13:40,831 10106 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'user=odoo sslmode=prefer dbname=ibda3vision'
2019-10-05 15:14:34,499 10104 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'user=odoo sslmode=prefer dbname=ibda3vision'
2019-10-05 15:14:46,951 10106 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'user=odoo sslmode=prefer dbname=ibda3vision'
2019-10-05 15:15:38,616 10104 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'user=odoo sslmode=prefer dbname=ibda3vision'
2019-10-05 15:15:53,067 10106 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'user=odoo sslmode=prefer dbname=ibda3vision'
2019-10-05 15:16:42,735 10104 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'user=odoo sslmode=prefer dbname=ibda3vision'
2019-10-05 15:17:02,342 10106 INFO ibda3vision odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_cron: Starting job `Download Data`.
2019-10-05 15:17:02,359 10106 INFO ibda3vision odoo.addons.oh_hr_zk_attendance.models.zk_machine: ++++++++++++Cron Executed++++++++++++++++++++++
2019-10-05 15:17:02,360 10106 ERROR ibda3vision odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_cron: Call from cron Download Data for server action #958 failed in Job #19
2019-10-05 15:17:02,362 10106 INFO ibda3vision odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_cron: Starting job `Mail: Fetchmail Service`.
2019-10-05 15:17:02,371 10106 INFO ibda3vision odoo.addons.fetchmail.models.fetchmail: start checking for new emails on pop server PROJECTS APPLICATIONS
2019-10-05 15:17:03,432 10106 INFO ibda3vision odoo.addons.fetchmail.models.fetchmail: start checking for new emails on pop server Recruitment
2019-10-05 15:17:06,260 10106 INFO ibda3vision odoo.addons.fetchmail.models.fetchmail: General failure when trying to fetch mail from pop server Recruitment .
2019-10-05 15:17:06,266 10106 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 3 connections to 'user=odoo sslmode=prefer dbname=ibda3vision'
2019-10-05 15:17:46,852 10104 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'user=odoo sslmode=prefer dbname=ibda3vision'
2019-10-05 15:18:06,784 10101 INFO ibda3vision werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Oct/2019 15:18:06] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/account.journal/retrieve_account_dashboard_setup_bar HTTP/1.0" 200 -
2019-10-05 15:18:06,858 10100 INFO ibda3vision werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Oct/2019 15:18:06] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.0" 200 -
2019-10-05 15:18:12,344 10106 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'user=odoo sslmode=prefer dbname=ibda3vision' ```

Any help is highly appreciated.
````

Comment: Did you set `max_connections` on `postgresql.conf`? Check documents https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/setup/deploy.html#configuring-odoo

Comment: @CharifDZ `max_connections` is set to 100.

Comment: But the log show that you where connected then disconnected! If you create a new database do you still have the same problem

Comment: @CharifDZ I'm using two databases in the same instance and facing the same issue in two of them. also not able to create new one

Comment: How did you create the firsr two?  Did you restore them?

Comment: yes i did restore them and was working fine, now im unable to take backup form database manager but got it from psql, and gives error when try to restore it in new odoo instance. @CharifDZ

Comment: When you restored did you set odoo as table owner?